# How to assess a Quantile Regression Model

Tags: model-evaluation, quantile-regression

I am trying to learn more about quantile regressions. In OLS Models, we can use statistics such as R-sqd and RMSE, MAE, MAPE etc to assess the accuracy/predictability of a model.
Is there any way to do the same for quantile regression models?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking this up in a textbook (chapter) on quantile regression? It should be there.

Comment: Books like Koenker "Quantile Regression" (2005), Hao & Naiman "Quantile regression" (2007), Davino et al. "Quantile Regression: Theory and Applications" (2013) all have something to say on the topic. Not sure how extensive the treatments are, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I also found this which is very helpful. https://rdrr.io/cran/WRTDStidal/man/goodfit.html